# Importing routes from file in Restify

Tags: node.js, restify, design-principles

I am working on understanding application structure and scalability. My current implementation is working but I have doubts about the implementation of it. I would like to avoid restify-router or other npm packages as much as possible. Unless there is a compelling reason.

This is my current setup:

app.js

```
const config = require('./config/config')
const restify = require('restify')

module.exports.server = restify.createServer({
  name: config.name,
  version: config.version
})

require('./routes')(this.server)
```

routes/index.js

```
module.exports = (server) => {
  require('./todo')(server)
}
```

routes/todo.js

```
const restify = require('restify')
const todoHandlers = require('../handlers/todoHandlers')

module.exports = (server) => {
  server.get('/todo', restify.plugins.conditionalHandler([
    { version: '1.0.0', handler: todoHandlers.getTodoHandlerV1 },
    { version: '2.0.0', handler: todoHandlers.getTodoHandlerV2 }
  ]))
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you be specific on what is your goal here and where do you need help?

Comment: @kabirbaidhya Thanks! My main question comes down to is this the proper way to load routes that are located in another file. By passing the (server) object as a parameter to the require statement.